# json data condtion for query

Tags: json, node.js

my server.js code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
if (par.query.login) {


var data={
    "user": {
        "displayName": "fares alkhawaja",
        "username": "elkhawajah"
    },
    "profile": {
             "photo":"null",
             "fullName": "fares sameer alkhawaja"   
    },
    "balance": {
        "overall": 200,
        "outstanding": 149
    },
    "currentTasks": [{
        "isProject": false,
        "id": "1234",
        "title": "Build NodeJS Application",
        "description": "This is a description for building nodejs application",
        "prize": "$500",
        "project": "topcoder",
        "holder": "elkhawajah"
    }, {
        "id": "134",
        "isProject": false,
        "title": "Build NodeJS Application",
        "description": "This is a description for building nodejs application",
        "prize": "$500",
        "project": "topcoder",
        "holder": "elkhawajah"
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "isProject": true,
        "title": "Build NodeJS Application",
        "description": "This is a description for building nodejs application",
        "prize": "$500",
        "project": "topcoder",
        "holder": "elkhawajah"
    }],
    "pastTasks": [{
        "isProject": false,
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Build NodeJS Application",
        "description": "This is a description for building nodejs application",
        "prize": "$500",
        "project": "topcoder",
        "holder": "fares"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "isProject": false,
        "title": "Build NodeJS Application",
        "description": "This is a description for building nodejs application",
        "prize": "$500",
        "project": "topcoder",
        "holder": "fares"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "isProject": true,
        "title": "Build NodeJS Application",
        "description": "This is a description for building nodejs application",
        "prize": "$500",
        "project": "topcoder",
        "holder": "fares"
    }],
    "timeline": [{
        "title": "Fares uploaded a new submission",
        "project": "tasqat",
        "task": "Build new endpoint",
        "date": new Date(),
        "handle": "fares"
    }, {
        "title": "Fares uploaded a new submission",
        "project": "tasqat",
        "task": "Build new endpoint",
        "date": new Date(),
        "handle": "fares"
    }]
}
}  
app.get("/dashboard", function(req, res) {

//send Jsondata to /view/dashboard.ejs
res.render('dashboard', data);

});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
console.log(process.env.PORT + ' is the magic port');
```

my problem is i need to use req.query.login... if req.query.login {return data} else {return nothing}

for example .. when i use http://localhost:3000/dashboard data should return nothing but if user login in http://localhost:3000/dashboard?login=true should return the data ...any help?

Comment: Unclear question.

Comment: @nicovank my question is : how to use json data under condtion ...if (req.query.login){var data=some data} else if not req.query.login var data=null .... like if http://localhost:3000/fares dont print the data but when i need to use http://localhost:3000/fares?login=true  print the data

Comment: Show your `controller` code here

Comment: i update my code ... i hope thats help

Comment: So you want to check for login in `/dashboard` controller ?

Comment: yes @Jyothi Babu Araja using query login

Comment: Then just keep that check (condition) inside `controller`

Comment: its return undefind par and query...can you explain with code ?? ...note : res.render('task-details',{user : 
         (req.query.login ? {i need to put the data her}:undefined) });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request a sample controller with condition for `query params`

```
var userData = {...}; //your data for user
```

Your Controller will be something like this

```
app.get("/dashboard", function(req, res) {

  var isLoggedIn = req.query.login; //assuming route as /dashboard?login=true
  var data = isLoggedIn? userData : {}; //empty object or null, whatever you want

  res.render('dashboard', data);

});
```

Comment: thnx @Jyothi Babu Araja for your answer.. i put var data before app.get dashboard and add your code inside app.get .. but return undefined data

Comment: @faresalkhawjaa You are getting `undefined` even `login=true`?

Comment: /dashboard?login=true its work ...but the page /dashboard its return undefined

Comment: So for route `/dashboard` what do you want to return instead of `undefined`?

Comment: the route /dashboard send data to page called dashboard.ejs in this page i print the data  example <user.username from the data > if the localhost:3000/dashboard?login=true but if the localhost:3000/dashboard i dont need to print the data ..so its work fine in localhost:3000/dashboard?login=true but in localhost:3000/dashboard return error undefiend  <user.username>

Comment: How can you call `user.username` without `login=true`. in your `.ejs` template. ?

Comment: using res.render('dashboard', data); thats send the data to dashboard.ejs

Comment: so when i use user.username or whatever from the data print it

Comment: you need to use `user.something` whenever user is `loggedin` otherwise show something else like `need to login first` etc..